# Should I run the AutoMapper configuration test in the unit tests suite or in the integration tests suite?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I created a test where I run the following AutoMapper assertion

```
        [Fact]
        public void Infrastructure_To_Core_Maps_Are_Valid()
        {
            var configuration = Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Configuration
                                   .AutoMapperConfig.CreateConfiguration();

            Action act = () => configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            act.ShouldNotThrow();
        }
```

Not sure if this should be considered an integration test. The test runs faster and I would like to do it at the same rate as the unit tests, but this means I have to get a dependency to AutoMapper.

Comment: Once running on test initialize is fine I guess

Comment: Well, i guess it depend on how strictly you separate the two and why you do that, e.g. the question is not technical, but rather a philosophical one. Specifically, i believe in one CI build, ideally on each commit (if you can afford it from the $$ perspective) -> so that you know exactly who broke the build. This way it doesn't matter what category you give the test because who cares - it runs once every commit anyway.